# If we have two solutions to an ODE, we will have an infinity ones?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\dot x=f(t,x)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$ be an initial value problem with $f$ continuous. If this problem has two solutions, we can say it has an infinity ones?

It's true to linear case, because every linear combination of the solutions is a solution of the problem, but I would like to know if this is valid in the general case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the [uniqueness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_solutions).

Comment: @StefanSmith yes, but how can we prove that these two solutions are unique? thank you for your comments.

Comment: @StefanSmith thank you!

Comment: But the solution $x=0$ is known as the trivial solution.

Comment: @StefanSmith But the solution x=0 is known as the trivial solution.

Comment: @user429012 : regardless of what you call it, $x \equiv 0$ is a valid solution of the ODE.

Comment: @user42912 : my answer was incorrect, so I deleted it.  If you look at Artem's comment, you can adapt his example to show that the IVP I gave (${\dot x} = x^{1/3},\ x(0) = 0$) actually has infinitely many solutions.  This doesn't necessarily mean that the answer to your question is "yes", just that my example was bad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $x$ and $y$ be two distinct solutions: that is, $x(t_0)=y(t_0)=x_0$ and $x(t_1)\ne y(t_1)$ for some $t_1>t_0$. Let $z$ be a solution of the initial value problem $z(t_1)=\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is strictly between $x(t_1)$ and $y(t_1)$. Moving backward in time from $t_1$, we observe that the solution $z$ exists as long as it stays between $x$ and $y$. At some moment $T\in [t_0,t_1)$ we must have $z(T)\in \{x(T),y(T)\}$. For definiteness assume $z(T)=x(T)$. Then the function 
$$\tilde z(t)=\begin{cases} x(t)\quad &t_0\le t\le T \\ z(t) & T\le t\le t_1 \end{cases}$$
solves the ODE and satisfies $\tilde z(t_0)=x_0$, $\tilde z(t_1)=\alpha$. Since there are uncountably many choices of $\alpha$, we have uncountably many solutions of the initial value problem.

That said, it is possible to have finitely many *germs* of solutions at $t_0$. For example, $\dot x=\frac32x^{1/3}$ with $x(0)=0$ has two germs:

- solutions that are $0$ in some neighborhood of $t=0$
- the solution $x(t)=t^{3/2}$ (with $x(t)=0$ for $t<0$)